# Add a 'name' to a Paragraph tag to work with POST

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a php project where I want to receive a _POST of a paragraph in my form.

What's the best way to do that ? 
I thought the easiest way to do that was adding a 'name' to the

tag but that seems not to work.

```
   <form action="Index.php" method=post enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
        foreach($optevragenDataVanWerknemer as $info)
        {
            echo "<p name = 'wnr'><strong>".$info->wnr."</strong></p> </br>";
            echo "<p> Afdeling : " . $info->afdeling . "</p>";
            echo "<p> Functie : " . $info->ftienaam . "</p>";
            echo "<p> Salaris : " . $info->salaris . "</p>";
            echo "<p> Vesnaam : " . $info->vesnaam . "</p>";
            echo "<p><img src='" . Config::getConfigInstantie()->getUploadMap() . '/' . $info->foto . "' alt=foto width=45 height=30></p>";
        ?>
            <p>
            <input type=hidden name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value=1000000>
            <label for=foto>Nieuwe foto </label>
            <input type=file name=foto id=foto>
            <input type=submit name=uploadKnop value="Upload Foto">
            </p>
        <?php
        }
?>



 $wnr = $_POST["wnr"]);
```

Comment: You question is not clear. Please elaborate it more.

Comment: A paragraph element is not a form element and will not be posted so it can be accessible in the `$_POST` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get only form elements ([Form Elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp)) in the action page ie from $_POST. You can better assign the same value to a hidden element and access it.

```
<form action="Index.php" method=post enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
        foreach($optevragenDataVanWerknemer as $info)
        {
            echo "<p><strong>".$info->wnr."</strong></p> </br>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name = 'wnr' value='{$info->wnr}'> </br>";

echo "<p> Afdeling : " . $info->afdeling . "</p>";
            echo "<p> Functie : " . $info->ftienaam . "</p>";
            echo "<p> Salaris : " . $info->salaris . "</p>";
            echo "<p> Vesnaam : " . $info->vesnaam . "</p>";
            echo "<p><img src='" . Config::getConfigInstantie()->getUploadMap() . '/' . $info->foto . "' alt=foto width=45 height=30></p>";
        ?>
            <p>
            <input type=hidden name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value=1000000>
            <label for=foto>Nieuwe foto </label>
            <input type=file name=foto id=foto>
            <input type=submit name=uploadKnop value="Upload Foto">
            </p>
        <?php
        }
?>
</form>
```

Comment: That is technically untrue that "You can get only input elements" : you get all forms elements (e.g.: textarea, select, submit buttons,...)

Comment: @Bartdude Exactly. Actually I meant form elements. Thanks

Comment: Thx this one worked :                 echo "<input type='hidden' name='wnr' value='$info->wnr'>";

Answer (score 2):

You need to have data you want in `$_POST` to be within a form element. A `<p>` tag will never submit data. Try `<textarea>` or `<input>`

```
foreach($optevragenDataVanWerknemer as $info) {
        echo "<textarea name = 'wnr'>" . $info->wnr . "\n";
        echo "Afdeling : " . $info->afdeling . "\n";
        echo "Functie : " . $info->ftienaam . "\n";
        echo "Salaris : " . $info->salaris . "\n";
        echo "Vesnaam : " . $info->vesnaam . "</textarea>";
}
```

I took out your `<img>` tag because that's an entirely different process to upload. If you're trying to store the raw HTML you could add it back into the `<textarea>` and it would submit as text.

Comment: As a side remark, an extensive client-side (optional) and server-side (mandatory) user-input validation is needed before storing raw HTML in the database in order to avoid XSS attacks.